# CASE When with Aggregation in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

considering the following dataframe

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [
    ('a', 5, 'voice'),
    ('a', 8, 'sim'),
    ('a', 7, 'sim'),
    ('b', 1, 'handset'),
    ('b', 3, 'sim')
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "val", "type"])


df.show()

+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  a|  5|  c|
|  a|  8|  d|
|  a|  7|  e|
|  b|  1|  f|
|  b|  3|  g|
+---+---+---+
```

I would like the apply the following spark sql query in Pyspark, but I can't figure out the syntax

```
df.createTempView('temp')

spark.sql(
"""
SELECT t.id
       ,    MAX(CASE WHEN t.type = 'voice'
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END) AS    feature_1
       ,    MAX(CASE WHEN t.type = 'sim'
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END) AS    feature_2
      FROM temp t
      GROUP BY t.id
"""
).show()

+---+---------+---------+
| id|feature_1|feature_2|
+---+---------+---------+
|  b|        0|        1|
|  a|        1|        1|
+---+---------+---------+
```

---

explain on above query

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[id#1615], functions=[max(CASE WHEN (type#1617 = voice) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), max(CASE WHEN (type#1617 = sim) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#1615, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#486]
   +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[id#1615], functions=[partial_max(CASE WHEN (type#1617 = voice) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), partial_max(CASE WHEN (type#1617 = sim) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)])
      +- *(1) Project [id#1615, type#1617]
         +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[id#1615,val#1616L,type#1617]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function [when](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) and [agg](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.agg)

```py
df.select(
   F.when(F.col('type') == 'voice', 1).otherwise(0).alias('feature_1_source'),
   F.when(F.col('type') == 'sim', 1).otherwise(0).alias('feature_2_source'),
   F.col('id')
).groupBy(
   F.col('id')
).agg(
   F.max(F.col('feature_1_source')).alias('feature_1'),
   F.max(F.col('feature_2_source')).alias('feature_2')
)
```

Comment: sorry I didn't get a notification for this for some reason! testing now

Comment: bril, thanks! this is logical and makes sense!